# How to fetch the response of JSON array in react native?

Tags: json, react-native

**rq.js**

```
}).then((responseData) =>{
        this.setState({
            user:responseData.name,
            user1:responseData.blood,
            user2:responseData.location,
            loaded: true,
        })
```

This is my code in react native.It works perfect if my JSON response is not an array.What change do i need to make in this code to work perfectly if json is an array?Showing this error `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1`

**data.json**

```
[{"name":"hema","bld":"O -ve","lc":"london"}]
```

this is my json array input.Anybody please help..

Answer (score 1):

try sending the data as a object not as array

```
{"name":"hema","bld":"O -ve","lc":"london"}
```

and actually you are calling props `blood` and `location`, but your JSON content `bld` and `lc` for that props

Answer (score 1):

If You want it work with an array just do

```
}).then((responseData) =>{
    this.setState({
        user:responseData[0].name,
        user1:responseData[0].blood,
        user2:responseData[0].location,
        loaded: true,
    })
```

in this way you are calling the first object of the array's index and then the prop of this first object in the array

Comment: Tried this but got the same error as before `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1`

Comment: are you getting that error in the browser?, can you send the entire JSON response?, are you using `JSON.parse` in any point? could be a error coming from the server, you have to check that you are actually sending `dataType: 'json'` from the server.

Comment: Yeah i'm getting the `json response`. and the response is like this `[{"name":"maria","bld":"B -ve","lc":"kochi"},{"name":"linu","bld":"AB +ve","lc":"kollam"},{"name":"minnu","bld":"AB +ve","lc":"kollam"}]`

Comment: @anu you got any solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late, but I hope it's helpful for others. How to fetch the response of JSON array in react native?

```
export default class ExpenseNew extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            accountnameMain:[],
        }
    }
     componentDidMount(){
         var account_nam=[]
                fetch('your Url', {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + your token }
                })
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((customerselect) => {
                        // alert(JSON.stringify(customerselect)) 
                        global.customerdata = JSON.stringify(customerselect)
                        var customername = JSON.parse(customerdata);
                        //alert(JSON.stringify(customername));
                        for (i = 0; i < customername.cus_data.length; i++) {
                            var dataa = customername.cus_data[i]["account_name"];  
                            account_nam.push(dataa)
                        }
                        this.setState({accountnameMain:account_nam});
                    })
                    .done();
    }
```

`account_name` is my field/column name, in your case, your column name is `bld` so you can fetch all data and push in var type of array, then set data in state type of array, and map anywhere you want.